# Запись и удаления из vector

Tags: c++

Как правильно удалять последний item из вот таких вот структур, и записывать следующий в самое начало, чтобы последующие iD повышались на 1.

```
#ifndef FOOTPRINTCURRENT_H
#define FOOTPRINTCURRENT_H
struct FootPrintCurrentData
{
    short iD;
    double lng;
    double lat;
    double alt;
};
#endif // FOOTPRINTCURRENT_H
```

main.h

```
std::vector<FootPrintCurrentData> footPrintCurrentData;
```

пытался удалить последний item, если он больше 39

```
for(int i = 0; i < footPrintCurrentData.size(); i++)
            {
                if(i > 39)
                {
                   footPrintCurrentData.erase(footPrintCurrentData.begin()+i, footPrintCurrentData.end());
                }
            }
```

при удалении, просто вылетает программа.

а вот как записывать в самое начало и смещать все на 1, т.е сортировать не пойму.

Comment: И с каким из этих шагов возникли затруднения и какие?

Comment: @VTT обновил вопрос

Comment: Чтобы записать в начало можно вызвать `vector::insert` и передать `begin` в качестве позиции

Comment: Что именно должен сделать приведенный выше код? Удалить все items начиная с 39-го?

Comment: @Julia после 39-го

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала вы удаляете от сорокового элемента до конца, и по циклу удаляете еще раз от 41 го до конца, от 42 го до конца. Бедный вектор...

### Можно удалить не в цикле, а можно переписать условие на

```
 if(i == 40)
            {
               footPrintCurrentData.erase(footPrintCurrentData.begin()+i, footPrintCurrentData.end());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если просто надо удалить после какой-то позиции, то цикл не нужен.
Вставлять в начало можно через insert.

```
int deleteAfter = 3;
if(footPrintCurrentData.size() > deleteAfter) {
    footPrintCurrentData.erase(footPrintCurrentData.begin() + deleteAfter, 
    footPrintCurrentData.end());
    footPrintCurrentData.insert(footPrintCurrentData.begin(), someVector);
}
```